# Objective C Comparing the name of an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a question, totally newbie but i would like to know how can i get to compare and image in an if else statement?

i have an image lets say it is "img.png" and i have it displayed in an imageview already in the application, however in the codes i would like to compare if the image show is "img.png"

I understand that for string we use the isEqualToString:, so if it's for an image what would i use?

example would be :

```
if ([img.image isEqual:@"img.png"])
```

What i've typed is something like this but it isnt working. could anyone point me in the right direction? thanks alot

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you first got the image using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]` you could compare the image object pointers: `if (img.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"])`.

But: I'd consider this bad design and would rather use another way of identifying images, like storing the name of the image in another instance variable.

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] will unnecessarily load UIImage into memory if it was not loaded so using separate instance variable is much much better I think.

Comment: @nikolai thank you for your reply (: i've gotten an idea on how to do it let me try and i'll get back!
@vladmir thanks for pointing about the memory (: